# Apache Server - Subdirectory on different server

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, wordpress, virtual-directory, directory

You have 2 different servers with different IP Addresses. Both servers are Apache based.

Server A: already hosts a website (http://example.com)

Server B: would host a WordPress website to be in a subdirectory of Server A (http://example.com/blog/)

Is this possible? If so, how.

(My background: I know very little about Apache Servers.)

Comment: Is this a school/homework question?

Comment: No, but I tried to make it sound like one. LOL

Comment: Don't do that - we don't do schoolwork.

Comment: Sorry, I write such clear and concise questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using: [mod_proxy - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html). for that you'd need to make sure both `Server A` and `Server B` up at all time though *OR* you can create another FQDN (blog.example.com) and point it to `Server B` and have it serve without `Server A`.